# Blazor - When to use Async life cycle methods

Tags: async-await, blazor

Is there any thumbrule for a beginner to understand when to use which life cycle methods, when developing a Blazor Server app.

`OnInitialized()` vs `OnInitializedAsync()` 
`OnParametersSet()` vs `OnParametersSetAsync()`
`OnAfterRender()` vs `OnAfterRenderAsync()`

Answer (score 4):

> OnInitialized() vs OnInitializedAsync()

Prefer the simple OnInitialized() to set data without async, like `message="hello";`.
As soon as you have to call and await async methods, for instance on HttpClient, switch to OnInitializedAsync().

More rules of thumb:

- do not use .Result or .Wait() on async methods
- do not start async methods without awaiting them
- do not use `async void` except in very rare cases.

When you get it wrong there will be an Error (can't await)  or a Warning:

> CS4032    The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

Is obvious, you should have used a *Async method. But **do not** 'fix' it by using  `async void` or `.Result`.

> CS1998    This async method lacks 'await' operators and will ...

means you should not have used the *Async method.

> CS4014    Because this call is not awaited, ...

means you are not awaiting something you should.

Comment: Sorry it's still unclear. The answer is more about how to use `Async`. Could you pls explain when to only use async over non-async, with any example.

Comment: It's really easy: when you need to `await` something then use the *Async methods. Otherwise use the simpler 'normal;' versions. The extra rules are to prevent you from wriggling out of these basic rules.

Comment: You need to be careful if you use both as the sync version of each is runs before the async version.

Comment: Yes. I would simply advice against using both. Too confusing.